# while setting cookies getting error of undefined index

Tags: php, html

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 setTimeout(function(){ 
 if(!mag_cookie_val)
  $("#myNav").show(); 
 }, 12000);  
 $("#close_magnet").click(function(){
  $("#myNav").hide(); 
 });
 $("#magnet_email").keyup(function(){
  $("#magnet_email").css("border-color","#67AEE9");    
 });

 $("#magnet_continue").click(function(){
  var MagEmail = $("#magnet_email").val();
  atpos = MagEmail.indexOf("@");
  dotpos = MagEmail.lastIndexOf(".");
  if(atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
  {
     $("#magnet_email").css("border-color","red");                   
  }else{
   /*
   $.ajax({
     url: "leadmagnet_res.php",
     method: 'POST',
     data:{magemail:MagEmail}
   }).done(function(data) {
    //alert(data)
     if(data !=0){
      $("#myNav").css("height","0%"); 
     }
   });
   */
   $.ajax({
    url: 'leadmagnet_res.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {magemail:MagEmail},
    //processData: false,
    success: function( res ){
     //alert(res);      
    },
    error: function(){
     alert( "error occured" );
    },
    complete: function(){
     $("#myNav").hide();
    }
   });
  }
 });


//Lead magnet close code End
$(document).ready(function() {
 
//setTimeout(function(){ $("#myNav").show(); }, 12000);
$("#magnet_email").css("border-color","#67AEE9");  
//Lead magnet close code start 
$("#close_magnet").click(function(){
$("#myNav").css("height","0%"); 
});

$("#magnet_email").keyup(function(){
 
$("#magnet_email").css("border-color","#67AEE9");    

});

$("#magnet_continue").click(function(){
var MagEmail = $("#magnet_email").val();
atpos = MagEmail.indexOf("@");
dotpos = MagEmail.lastIndexOf(".");
if(atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
{
//alert(1);
   $("#magnet_email").css("border-color","red");         
           
}else
{
 //alert(2);  
$.ajax({
   url: siturl_mag+"leadmagnet_res.php",
  method: 'POST',
  data:{magemail:MagEmail}
}).done(function(data) {
 //alert(data)
  if(data !=0){
   $("#myNav").css("height","0%"); 
  }
  
});
    
}
 
});

//Lead magnet close code End
 </script>
```

```css
   <style>

.overlay_magnet {
    height: 0% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    z-index: 94 !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay_magnet-content {
    margin-left: 27%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 45%;
}



.overlay_magnet a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay_magnet a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay_magnet .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay_magnet {}
  .overlay_magnet a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay_magnet .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
.circle_magnet {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FE0000;
    border-width:4px;
}
.circle_magnet-wrapper {
    margin: 0 5%;
    position: relative;
}
.circle_magnet .list-inline {
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
.circle_magnet .list-inline li {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
}
.circle_magnet p {
    padding-top: 10%;
    margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width:460px) { 
 .circle_magnet .list-inline li {
     font-size: 50px;
     display: inline-block;
 }
 .circle_magnet-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
        margin:0 auto;
 }
 .circle_magnet {
     height: 0px;
     padding: 50%;
     border-radius: 50%;
 }
 .circle_magnet > div {
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
     left: 10%;
     right: 10%;
     top: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
        top:20%\9; /* ie8 hack test this out it's a guess */
 }
}

.circle_text_magnet{
cursor:pointer; 
 
}

.circle_text_magnet:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}

   .arrow{
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
  }


</style>
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay_magnet hidden-xs hidden-sm" <?php if ($magstatus !=0){?>style="height:0% !important;display:none;" <?php }else{ ?>style="height:100% !important;display:none;" <?php } ?> >
<div class="overlay_magnet-content" >
<div class="circle_magnet-wrapper">
<div class="circle_magnet text-center">
<div class="row" style="margin-top:-40%;">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
  <center>
  <label style="font-family: Roboto;color: green;text-shadow: rgb(46, 46, 46) 0px 4px 5px;font-size: 42px;font-weight: bold !important;margin: 0 !important;">Sign Up!</label>
  
  </center>
 </div> 
 </div>
   
 <div class="row" style="margin-top:-24%;">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
  <center>
  <label style="font-family: Roboto;color: #00006A;font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal !important;margin: 0 !important;">Join our Travel Community.</label>
  <label style="font-family: Roboto;color: #00006A;font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal !important;margin: 0 !important;">Get Free Exclusive Travel Tips and<br> Links to our New Travel Videos.</label>
  </center>
 </div> 
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="row" style="margin-top:-12%;">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
  <center>
  
  <label style="font-family: Roboto;color: #fe0000;font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal !important;margin: 0 !important;">Enter your email below</label>

    </center>
 </div> 
 </div>
 
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid #00006A;border-radius: 7px;padding: 18px;box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px 0px #ABABAB, 0px 2px 9px 1px #242424;">

  <div class="col-md-9">   
 <input id="magnet_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address " type="text"  > 
 </div>
 
<div class="col-md-3" >  
<button  class="btn btn-primary pull-left " id="magnet_continue">Continue</button>&nbsp; 
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20%;">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
 
  <span style="font-family: Roboto;color: #00006A;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal !important; ">By clicking Continue, I agree to the </span>
  <span><a href="<?php echo $urbtn;?>hipfig-terms-of-use" style="font-size:12px;font-family: Roboto;color: #fe0000;"> Terms of Service</a></span>
   
 </div> 
 </div>






        <div class="row" style="margin-top:35%;">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
  <center><h2 id="close_magnet" class="circle_text_magnet" style="font-family: Roboto;color: #00006A;font-weight: normal !important; margin-left:10px; ">No Thanks</h2></center>
  </div> 
   </div>

      
   </div>
    
</div>

</div>
```

this is a code of cookies which i m setting for a form to be displayed

but always getting a error of Undefined

> index: MagnetStatus in line 3

which is

```
$magstatus = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
```

code:

```
$magstatus = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

if(!$magstatus) {

$cookie_value = 0;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}

?>
```

so can u help me out or any idea regarding this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4730578/8197560

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `isset()` or `empty()` to prevent such warnings if the cookie with the specified name doesnt exist

```
$magstatus = (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) ? $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] : 'default_value_here';
```

Comment: when i am using this line of code getting blank screen and

Comment: make sure `$cookie_name` is defined - the snippet works fine on my end

Comment: when i am using empty() same error getting and can u explain default_value_here what is this?

Comment: is any where else i have to define $cookie_name ? just simply i had written only that much cookies code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following code to check whether cookie is set or not:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

$cookie_value = 0;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

Remove `$magstatus = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];` line only check cookie with `isset` method

Comment: after removing that line no error is there can u check all code

Comment: cookies is set by doing this but i have to define this in form and while doing this i am getting same error see html from code in line one ie.  <?php if ($magstatus !=0){?>style="height:0% !important;display:none;" <?php }else{ ?>style="height:100% !important;display:none;" <?php } ?> >

Comment: i am using this code showing cookies are not enabled $cookie_name = "MagnetStatus";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

$cookie_value = 1;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}

if (isset($_GET['cookiecheck'])) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['testcookie'])) {
        print "Cookies are enabled";
    } else {
        print "Cookies are not enabled";
    }
} else {
    setcookie('testcookie', "testvalue");
    die(header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?cookiecheck=1"));
}